# DXA 1.1 CT Question. How do I use the HTML Class field in the CT?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, dxa

The "Component Template Metadata" that's part of  DXA has this field: HTML class(es) (if multiple, separate by a space).  How do I reference that on a view?  I have two blocks of content that are structured very similarly & that would be a perfect way to only use one view.  Each unique style can have its own class in the CT.

Can that be added to the model semantics so that it comes thru that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That piece of metadata is automatically mapped to the `HtmlClasses` property of the View Model (each View Model inherits that property from class `ViewModel`).
View code can include it in the HTML using `Model.HtmlClasses` (see, for example, the Core Views).

This facility indeed allows you to have diffently styled views based on the same view code.